# how to use the same ajax call on the created dropdown list

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

dears , i have one table to show the list of category and i need to add unlimited drop down list which will be nested from the parent 
like
category  A 
Category B , if selected B it will add another dropdown and added it into data base and will add another dropdown list sub b1 , sub 2 and if user select sub 2 will do the same

can anyone help 
 
        $(document).ready(function(){

```
        //$('.form-control').change(function(){ 

         $('select.form-control').on('change', function () {
             var selectedCategory = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

             var counter = 1;
          //alert( $(this).find('option:selected').text());
         //var deptid = $('#category option:selected').attr("id");
              var name = "Sub "+ $(this).children("option:selected").text();

         if(selectedCategory!=''){

           $.ajax({
                 url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>category/add_new",
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: {'category_parent':selectedCategory,'category_name':name},
                 dataType: 'json',
                 async: false ,
                 cache:false,
                 success:function(data){
                   alert(data);
                   if($('#category'+data).length)
                          return;
                      else{
                           $("#groupd").after('<div id="sub'+data+'" class="form-group">' +
                       '<label>' +name +' : </label>' +
                       '<select class="form-control" name="dropdown' + counter + '"  id="category'+data+'">' +
                        // Add your options here...
                       '<option>Please Select</option>'+
                       '<option value="'+data+'">'+name +'1</option>'+
                       '<option value="'+data+'">'+name +'2</option>'+
                       '</select></div>');
                        counter++; 
                      }
                   },

                error:function(){
                      alert('error');
                }
    });
         }


        }); 

    });
</script>
```